# Почему не работает sort()

Tags: javascript

не могу понять, почему не работает `sort((a, b) => b - a)`, но когда делаю просто `sort()` - работает?

```js
function isIsogram(str){
  return str.split('').sort((a,b) => a - b);
  
}

console.log(isIsogram("Dermatoglyphics"));
```

Comment: а просто `(a,b) => a > b` не пойдет?

Comment: @teran тогда ситуации a<b и a==b будут считаться одинаковыми (ибо a>b для обоих даст false), что, боюсь, может привести к странностям в поведении сортировки

Comment: @andreymal да черт ее пойми. по идее приведет к тому, что равные элементы все равно будут переставляться, то есть увеличится число шагов, но сортировка вроде завершится успешно.

Comment: @teran, такой компаратор не является "consistent comparison function". Спецификация языка не определяет поведение функции `sort` с таким компаратором. См. [Array.prototype.sort](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что здесь

```
a - b
```

строки преобразуются в числа.

```
"D" -> NaN
"e" -> NaN
"r" -> NaN
```

Ваш компаратор всегда возвращает `NaN`.

Ваши односимвольные строки можно сравнить

```
(a, b) => a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0
```

или так

```
(a, b) => a.codePointAt(0) - b.codePointAt(0)
```

А если нужно сравнивать не по кодам символов, а по языковым правилам, то можно так

```
(a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)
```

Comment: @nörbörnën, `localCompare(a, b)`?